# Required a Cross Platform SDK or a BaaS technology for a calendar app

Tags: android, ios, calendar, aws-sdk

Looking for a cross platform SDK or a BaaS platform which will allow to create calendar based app where each user will have their own separate calendar irrespective of the synced calendars [Google iOS Facebook]

For maintaining the user credentials and the associated calendars..

Please advice..

Thank You

Comment: Do you know phonegap? cross platform

Comment: phonegap will help for the frontend but what about the backend?